# Selection Sort Issue: Why is the biggest element of the list put at the front of the list?

Tags: python, selection-sort

I've been practicing SELECTION SORT using Python 3 with a list of lists I read from a file. I'm trying to print the list in increasing order of the first element of each inner list (List[i][0]).

This is my list:
[[130.0, 266.07], [46.0, 174.14], [169.0, 187.01], [179.0, 488.69], [53.0, 401.53], [128.0, 106.88], [97.0, 398.33], [152.0, 493.87], [20.0, 205.43], [94.0, 248.14]]

However, with this code:

```
def swapElements(aList, a, b):
    temp = aList[a]
    aList[a] = aList[b]
    aList[b] = temp

def selection_sort(aList):
    for i in range(0, len(aList)):
        minimum = 0
        for j in range(i, len(aList)):
            if aList[j][0] < aList[minimum][0]:
                minimum = j
        if minimum != i:
            swapElements(aList, i, minimum)
    print(aList)
```

the output always puts the biggest element of the list at the start:

[[179.0, 488.69], [20.0, 205.43], [46.0, 174.14], [53.0, 401.53], [94.0, 248.14], [97.0, 398.33], [128.0, 106.88], [130.0, 266.07], [152.0, 493.87], [169.0, 187.01]]

Can anyone please explain why and show where my code is wrong?

Comment: swap in python can be done much more elegant: `lst[a], lst[b] = lst[b], lst[a]`.

Comment: You want just the inner loop list to be sorted or the outer list also. You can put your expected results which gives more depth to your question. It will be easy for others to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you ranges are slightly off. compare with the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). the altorithm there in your notation:

```
def swapElements(lst, a, b):
    lst[a], lst[b] = lst[b], lst[a]

def selection_sort(aList):
    for i in range(len(aList)-1):         # -1 is vital!
        minimum = i                       # the minimum index starts at i; not 0
        for j in range(i+1, len(aList)):  # here it's the +1
            if aList[j][0] < aList[minimum][0]:
                minimum = j
        if minimum != i:
            swapElements(aList, i, minimum)
    print(aList)
```

and as i mentioned in the comment: python can swap values simply like this: `lst[a], lst[b] = lst[b], lst[a]`.